# Firing Events With Yii2

Tags: yii2

I'm trying to understand how I can apply event handlers to events in a Yii2 application. From reading the docs I believe I can fire off an event using this.

```
$this->trigger('failedTransaction');
```

However I am trying to understand where I put the handlers that are used for running when the failedTransaction event is fired.

Comment: Did you read https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-events ?

Comment: Yes but I"m having a hard time grasping how Yii2 handles it.

Comment: The third section (Attaching Event Handlers) explains how events handlers are attached. What is unclear in it?

Comment: I would like to create a class for each Handler and create a handle method for each of the handlers to call when the event is triggered.  Would I do this in the config file. 'on failedTransaction' => function ($event) {
        $event->on(MyEventHandlerClass::handle);
    },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [class-level events](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-events#class-level-event-handlers) for this. You can attach this on your app bootstrap (and probably in config, before app is initialized):

```
Event::on(
    MyClass::class, 
    MyClass::FAILED_TRANSACTION_EVENT, 
    [MyEventHandlerClass::class, 'handle']
);
```

Then whenever `MyClass` will call `$this->trigger(self::FAILED_TRANSACTION_EVENT);`, `MyEventHandlerClass::handle()` will be called to handle this event.

You can also use [global events](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-events#global-events). In your config:

```
'on failedTransaction' => [MyEventHandlerClass::class, 'handle'],
```

And trigger event by `Yii::$app->trigger('failedTransaction')` - this will also call `MyEventHandlerClass::handle()` to handle this event.